# Remove duplicate common output from two list

Tags: java

I have two arrays. I want the output to be the common numbers between the two lists, but with the code below it will output the duplicate common numbers.

```
 double[] arr1 = {100.00, 100.00, 17246.40, 2568.00, 0.20, 9845.00, 5768.18, 0.20, 30.00,
      63.68, 83.56, 444.39, 144.20, 2889.00};

 double[] arr2 = {2000.90, 508.07, 100.00, 17246.40, 5899.38, 17246.40, 17246.40, 2568.00,
      83.56, 144.20, 2889.00, 3000.00, 2568.00, 60.00, 3135.00, 28329.91, 3135.00, 9845.00};

 for(int i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
      for(int j=0; j<arr2.length; j++){
           if(arr1[i] == arr2[j]){
                System.out.println(arr1[i]);
```

Can anyone help to just output the common number between both of the arrays and remove the duplicate numbers?

Thanks.

Comment: use set if you don't want to have duplicates

Comment: You have  `Array`s and not  `List`s of array.  Next, in the loop instead of printing the number, add it to a `Set` and then print the numbers outside the loop.

Comment: Searching for duplicates in double is dangerous as they may differ in a decimal place not even visible. If you need two decimal places multiply your values by 100 and convert them to an int or long.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Create a set and simply add the common values to it.

```
double[] arr1 = {100.00, 100.00, 17246.40, 2568.00, 0.20, 9845.00, 5768.18, 0.20, 30.00, 63.68, 83.56, 444.39, 144.20, 
                2889.00};


double[] arr2 = {2000.90, 508.07, 100.00, 17246.40, 5899.38, 17246.40, 17246.40, 2568.00, 83.56, 144.20, 2889.00, 3000.00, 
                2568.00, 60.00, 3135.00, 28329.91, 3135.00, 9845.00};

Set<Double> set = new HashSet<Double>();

for(int i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){

     for(int j=0;j<arr2.length;j++){
           if(arr1[i]==arr2[j])
                set.add(arr1[i]);
     }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(set.toArray()));
```

Comment: there is no need for a loop in a loop. Your if clause isn't necessary, too. Because you can store a value only once in a set.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @dr_debug Yes but I need to check for the common elements right?

Comment: @AnnMathews no there is no need to do that

Comment: @dr_debug If I remove the if clause, it would simply return the elements in both the arrays without the duplicates whereas the question was for the common elements without duplicates.

Comment: @AnnMathews no. remove the clause and give it a try. and have a look at [the api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

Comment: @dr_debug I did. What it gives is all the elements in both the arrays, without duplicates, just as the api says, I agree. But, the output required here, as I understand it, is to print the elements that are present in **both** the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Store your values in a set. A set eliminates duplicates automatically.

```
 Set<Double> set = new HashSet<Double>();

 for(int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
   set.add(arr1[i]);
 }
 for(int j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++){
   set.add(arr2[j]);
 }

 Double[] array = set.toArray(new Double[0]);
 // Output goes here
 System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

If length of arr1 is the same as arr2 you can handle this in one for loop

Answer (score 1):

What about Streams? *Might* be more efficient (no need to create a set) and quicker (see the parallel distinction and sort)

```
 double[] arr1 = {100.00, 100.00, 17246.40, 2568.00, 0.20, 9845.00, 5768.18, 0.20, 30.00,
            63.68, 83.56, 444.39, 144.20, 2889.00};

    double[] arr2 = {2000.90, 508.07, 100.00, 17246.40, 5899.38, 17246.40, 17246.40, 2568.00,
            83.56, 144.20, 2889.00, 3000.00, 2568.00, 60.00, 3135.00, 28329.91, 3135.00, 9845.00};

    DoubleStream stream1 = Arrays.stream(arr1);
    DoubleStream stream2 = Arrays.stream(arr2);
    Stream<Double> concat = Stream.concat(stream1.boxed(), stream2.boxed());
    concat.parallel().distinct().sorted().sequential().forEach(System.out::println);
```

As noone posted an output before:

```
0.2
30.0
60.0
63.68
83.56
100.0
144.2
444.39
508.07
2000.9
2568.0
2889.0
3000.0
3135.0
5768.18
5899.38
9845.0
17246.4
28329.91
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
for(int i=0; i<arr1.length; i++){
      for(int j=0; j<arr2.length; j++){
           if(arr1[i] == arr2[j]){
                System.out.println(arr1[i]);
                break;
           }
      }
}
```

You are getting duplicate values as you are comparing each element of first array with all the elements of other array. So if a value will occur twice in second array, that will be printed. Just break the inner loop when one item is matched, it will remove the duplicate items.